# How to list all subcollections of a Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image]

Hi,
I have a problem with downloading all collections from the document. I would like after finding the id (userUid) document to be able to download all its collections, I need the id of each of these collection

```
export const getAllMessagesByUserId = async (userUid) => {
  const result = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(userUid)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article which proposes solutions to this problem: [How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) As a matter of fact, "**retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries**" as explained in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

I would suggest you use the second method proposed in the article, using a Cloud Function.

Here is the code copied from the article.

*Cloud Function:*

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getSubCollections = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const docPath = data.docPath;

    const collections = await admin.firestore().doc(docPath).listCollections();
    const collectionIds = collections.map(col => col.id);

    return { collections: collectionIds };

});
```

---

*Example of calling the Cloud Function from a web app:*

```
  const getSubCollections = firebase
    .functions()
    .httpsCallable('getSubCollections');

  getSubCollections({ docPath: 'collectionId/documentId' })
    .then(function(result) {
      var collections = result.data.collections;
      console.log(collections);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Getting the Error details.
      var code = error.code;
      var message = error.message;
      var details = error.details;
      // ...
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve this without paying, because i must pay for this function

Comment: There is a generous free tier of 2 millions invocations by month for Cloud Functions. So you will probably not go over this limit and therefore you will not pay. However you need to register a credit card for using Cloud Functions, even if you don’t pay anything.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to return information about it when a new collection is added to a given document?

Comment: There isn't any trigger for this event. You could trigger a Cloud Function when a doc is added to any subcollection of a given doc but it seems a bit "overpowered" for your need.